# Reading from file using dict comprehensions

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I regularly need to read data from (typically tab-separated value) files and convert them to dicts. Usually I just need to map one of the columns to another, but there could be some processing of the values (such as stripping whitespace) as well. I've been trying to come up with a dict comprehension pattern to do that, but I keep running into small nuisances that keep me from implementing it the most succinct and understandable way consistently. And I have a feeling that there probably is a better way.

So here are (some of the) ways I have tried, and where they went wrong:

---

```
with open(path) as f:
    return {line.split("\t")[0].strip(): line.split("\t")[1].strip()
            for line in f}
```

This is what I often end up using. It allows me to modify key and value in place, and would work on any of the columns (e.g. if i wanted to map values from the third to the first column). The obvious problem is the duplication of the `line.split()` part. Is there a way to bind `line.split("\t")` to a temporary variable, or unpack the values directly into variables?

---

```
with open(path) as f:
    return dict(line.split("\t")[:2] for line in f)
```

I just came up with this. It works nicely for this simple case (just mapping the first to the second column, without any processing), but doesn't generalize to other cases. Additional processing is hard to do and the columns used have to be adjacent. It is also not a strict dict comprehension, and can't be turned into one because it is using slices.

---

```
d = dict()
for line in open(path):
    d.update({line.split("\t")[0]: line.split("\t")[1]})
return d
```

Of course, I could just create the dict first and then update with every line. But now I have to create the dict and return it separately, and the code duplication is still there.

---

I have also played around with nested dict comprehensions and unpacking the splitted line into variables, but ran into different problems with that.

Comment: You're trying to optimize something that is likely I/O bound, so nothing you do as far as creating the dictionaries as fast or with the least amount of code is likely to make much of a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort of do that, by putting something around your `f`:

```
def tabsplit(file_object):
    for line in file_object:
        yield line.split("\t")
```

And then later:

```
with open(path) as f:
    return {left.strip(): right.strip() for left, right, *rest in tabsplit(f)}
```

Comment: Interesting, I haven't tried using generators in any way... However, this is where the unpacking problems that I have hinted at earlier come into play. The input files might contain differening numbers of tabs - there might be trailing values that belong to the last column, for example. These files would then throw a ValueError, which I don't know how to handle in a dict comprehension. The files also usually contain other columns that don't need to be in the dict - ignoring them by unpacking them into _, _, ... might be possible but I don't find that very elegant either.

Comment: So you want to ignore every column except for the first two? See my edit to throw away the `*rest`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why creating dictionary first won't work

```
result = {}
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        columns = line.split("\t")
        key = columns[0] # first item is the key right?
        result[key] = columns[1]
```

Comment: Of course it does work, but I'm trying to make this as succinct as possible. Which is why I don't like the separate declaration and return steps - even if this would be one of the most readable solutions.

Comment: @Sebastian: Succinct is not always == better. Readability and maintainability counts for a lot and efficiency often doesn't matter...like 97% of the time. See [_When to optimize_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: @martineau I know, which is exactly why I'm asking this question. Finding a code pattern I can always use for this would allow me to use it consistently, thus increasing maintainability and understandability in the long run. And if I can find a pattern with fewer lines, I would probably prefer that simply because it's less scrolling - I tend to work in a IPython notebook, and the additional lines add up pretty quickly...

Comment: @Sebastian: Both of these answers do that well-enough. To minimize the number of line, make it utility function...similar to what L3viathan did but onr level further up. Splitting a task up into chunks can often be helpful in a number of ways.